# Using hstore in Rails to let user input attribute and value dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I am trying to use the hstore gem in Rails and I want to create a form where the user can input the attribute and the value both. Suppose I have a `properties` hstore column in my table and an example hash would be `properties => {"x": "y"}` where x and y are entered in and the attribute is created dynamically.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at railscasts.com and watch the HStore episode.  It'll show you how to set everything up...  It also has a nice metaprograming example.

Comment: Oh, and to accept the attribute at the same time as the main form would be difficult.  Any chance you can use a multi-step-form (e.g., where the user enters the X value first and then enters the y value on the response page?

Comment: Can you help me with the multi-step-form?

Comment: Can you share come code?  Starting off with the model and the migration file would be helpful.

Comment: [product.rb](http://pastebin.com/8SP2b7SS) and [migration](http://pastebin.com/5EmyFXxL)

Comment: Did you first run the Hstore generate command? rails g hstore:setup  (which essentially creates a migration with the following: execute "CREATE EXTENSION hstore")?

Comment: Yes everything is setup. Hstore is setup. All the migrations also are done and run. Hstore is working also.

Comment: I see you've changed your post above from 'I'm getting PG errors' to 'Can you help me with the multi-step-form.'  Yes, I can help you with the form.  Let me know what you are having trouble with and I'll point you in the correct direction.  FYI, there's also a Railscast on form wizards that will probably help you.  Yes, ryanb is awesome.